# SpringMVC RadioButton Form Not Working

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm a beginner struggling with SpringMVC. The Form is a single row of RadioButtons. The goal is, when Submit is clicked, re-display this form with the selection currently stored in the model.

My current error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

Controller: SFController.java

```
@Controller
public class SFController {


    @RequestMapping("/sf")
    public ModelAndView showInitial(final HttpServletRequest request) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/jsp/forms/sf.jsp", "sfModel", new SFModel());                                

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sfResult")
    public ModelAndView showResult(final HttpServletRequest request, 
                                   @ModelAttribute SFModel sfModel) {


        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/jsp/forms/sf.jsp", "sfModel", sfModel);                                

        return mav;
    }
```

JSP (sf.jsp)

```
    <form:form method="POST" action="/sfResult">            


            <form:radiobutton path="type" value="a" />a <br/>
            <form:radiobutton path="type" value="b" />b.<br/>
            <form:radiobutton path="type" value="c" />c <br/>
            <form:radiobutton path="type" value="d" />d <br/>
            <form:radiobutton path="type" value="e" />e <br/>

        <input value="Submit" type="submit">  

    </form:form>
```

Model, SFModel.java:

```
public class SFModel {

    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I was missing the **command** name reference in the Form tag in the JSP.

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="sfModel" action="/sfResult">
```